# Reading usb printer status in Java

Tags: java, windows, printing, usb, raw-data

I'm developing a program in Java over Windows 7 which uses a POS printer connected through USB. I started with the common PrintJob using the print spool, but it's not enough. I need to control more things than the driver is able to.

So I'm sending raw data with all the commands written by myself. I've achieved this thanks to **norbi771**'s answer here [Print Zebra ZM400 using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935755/print-zebra-zm400-using-java#comment24454515_16937513) . So I've shared the printer on the network and I'm creating an OutputStream to send the raw data to \localhost\myprinter

This works great, my problem comes when I try to open an InputStream to read the printer status. This model has some commands to ask for some status and the printer answers inmediatly. Manual says:

*The status is transmitted whenever the data sequence is received. The printer transmits the current status represented by one-byte data. The printer transmits the status without confirming whether the host computer can receive data.*

Then, I'm able to send raw data (I'm printing using same schema and url) but when I try to read the status I'm geting a FileNotFoundException. 
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: \localhost\myprinter, (The system cannot find the file specified)**. How is it possible to not find it for input, but yes for output?

Does anybody know how could I read the info sent by the printer? Here's my code so far. I'm executing this in a thread each 5 seconds, so is not a "not ready/connected" printer. I've even try to sleep before creating the InputStream, but nothing works. Is there any other way to connect to read it?

```
FileOutputStream os; FileInputStream is;
PrintStream ps = null; InputStreamReader reader = null;
char[] askStatus = {0x10, 0x04, 0x02};
String port = "\\\\localhost\\myprinter";
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(port);
    ps = new PrintStream(os);

    ps.print(askStatus);
    ps.flush();
    //Everything fine until here
    //sleep(1000);

    is = new FileInputStream(port); //This line throws the Exception
    reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    if (reader.ready()) {
    int status = reader.read();
    System.out.println("Status: " + Integer.toBinaryString(status));
    }
} catch (Ex...) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use USB access to the printer for which you'll need something like [JUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/). I understand that the windows implementation has some limitations that carries from using libusb.

If you are lucky you'll be able to request the status using that. If not you'll have to use the GET_PORT_STATUS request for USB Class printer to get the status like explained in [this page](http://forum.silabs.com/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=38728).

I haven't found a full working example of this yet.